# D-Link DWR-M960 Country or Region locked at UAE

Tags: router

I have just installed a new D-Link DWR-M960 router and find that the 'Country or Region' which is accessed via 'Settings' and then 'Wi-Fi' is greyed out and locked to the United Arab Emirates. That in itself is not a problem but it causes my smartphone to think it is in Bandar-e Torkeman, Golestan which is in Iran and I am in Ghana, West Africa. It also interferes with my Huawei smart watch which thinks the same!
I have searched and searched for a way to change the router's 'Country and Region' setting to no avail. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to factory-reset the router.

I would also suggest to download and install the latest firmware
[DWR-M960 FW Ver. 1.1.36](https://dlinkmea.com/index.php/product/details?det=azZBaklEMHdPVjFrK25YZzZWeXVpdz09#menu3),
from the Downloads section.

These operations should clear all the existing settings, so note down
well those settings that you wish to keep.

Comment: Thanks very much, my problem is now resolved, GREAT!!!